# T-SQL to CAML - I wonder what's missing in the CAML (T-SQL works)

Tags: caml-query, caml, sql

I have this SQL query and it works perfectly. However, when I try to create a similar CAML it doesn't work. Is there a tool that can convert SQL to CAML. or can someone please help. Here is the SQLFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0557ef/10

```
select assignedto
from sample_approvers_list
where
libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and LineName = 'pure'
or
(libraryname='packaging' and level='a' and AnyLine='Yes')
```

[image]

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Level' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>            
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='LineName' />
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
                </Eq>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLine' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq> 
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyPlace' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>          
            </Or>           
        </And>
    </And>  
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following CAML worked.

```
<Query>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
</ViewFields>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Level' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>            
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Line' />
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
                </Eq>               
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLine' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>               
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```